# What are the best user research practices when launching a beta site with a very small # of first users?

Tags: usability, user-research, users, user-interviews, beta

I believe it is a good idea to conduct user interviews to understand experience of first users soon after they try out the site.
What are some types of helpful question examples that might be relevant? What's a healthy # of users to try to conduct interviews with after BETA launch?

Answer (score 1):

I usually kick off with around 12-15 users. In terms of what questions to ask really depends on the type of site you are building. For example, user interview questions for an eLearning app could include the following:

- How they learn a new concept online. What steps do they follow?
- Describe a typical day at school/work.
- What makes a good day in their current routine? How about a bad one?
- What activities waste their time?
- How do they approach problems and how do they solve them?
- What shortcuts do they use on web/apps?
- How they expect a course to be structured
- What expectations do they have from a learning app?
- What features do they expect from the app?
- What features they think would be great but don't necessarily expect?
- What do they enjoy about the experience?
- What issues do they face?
- When might they use the app?
- Where might they use it?
- Would they like to use it in a group experience?

Here are some brilliant resources that will help you plan the process:

https://uxdesign.cc/how-to-conduct-user-interviews-fe4b8c34b0b7

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/user-interviews/

https://medium.com/@mitchelseaman/the-right-number-of-user-interviews-de11c7815d9

Comment: Thank you Mihnea, I was wondering what questions are good to ask once Beta users have at least tried the MVP site, to discover gaps for improvement. And how soon to ask once  you know they have tried the site. Or is it crucial to see them react to it first time using it (live)?  That part I'm a bit confused about.

Also thanks for helpful links!

Comment: Well, in a situation like this you would probably want to run a usability test. This is a method where you ask your users to complete specific tasks and observe any potential problems that might show up when completing said tasks.

Comment: How long would you say is a healthy amount of time after beta users have themselves   tried your site to ask for feedback?

Comment: Well, in usability testing you would do that right away, in real-time, before deploying the website. Alternatively, you can send a survey after around two weeks (or however long it takes for a user to successfully accomplish their goal using your website) to the users who have been most active on the beta site (they are called pilot users)